# How to redirect an outlook mail using pywin32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

old message is initial message and new message is the message I want to forward. This is what I have tried, it does not seem to work. I cant use send On behalf of an send Using Account as it means I need to have the original sender in my mailbox.

```
NewMsg = oldmessage.Forward()
NewMsg.ReplyRecipients.Add(oldmessage.SenderEmailAddress)
NewMsg.Recipients.ResolveAll
NewMsg.Save         
NewMsg.Body = oldmessage.Body
NewMsg.Subject = "Forwarded to Treat: " + oldmessage.Subject
NewMsg.To = abc@outlook.com
NewMsg.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep the original sender - Outlook has no idea that you are trying to redirect, and Outlook (and Exchange server) will prevent you from spoofing an arbitrary sender.

In the old Exchange world, one could create a server-side rule that used `FWD_PRESERVE_SENDER | FWD_DO_NOT_MUNGE_MSG` flags and the action of `OP_FORWARD`, but I don't think Outlook uses these flags nowadays, but Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) can probably still be used to create a rule like that.

**EDIT**: Server-side rules that preserve the sender and the message can still be created using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdorule.htm) (I am its author):

```
FWD_PRESERVE_SENDER = 1
FWD_DO_NOT_MUNGE_MSG = 2
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Store = Session.Stores.DefaultStore
set Rules = Store.Rules
set Rule = Rules.Create("Test redirect")

set Action = Rule.Actions.Redirect
set Recip = Action.Recipients.Add("user@domain.demo")
Recip.Resolve
Action.Enabled = true
Action.Flags = FWD_PRESERVE_SENDER + FWD_DO_NOT_MUNGE_MSG

Rule.ConditionsAsSQL = "Subject like '%test redirect%'"
Rule.Enabled = true
Rule.Save
```

Comment: You are correct, I have been researching on how to create a server side rule, I have not found any useful guide.

Comment: Rules like that can be created using Redemption (I am its author) - see above.

Comment: Wow, this is cool. I will try it immediately.

Comment: I am a bit confused about 2 things,

(1) Do I still need to create an outlook object with win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')? If yes, the at what point do I create the Redemption object? Before Forwarding the mail with mailitem.Forward?

   ( 2) I am using Python, and all the comments I have seen about implementing 
    Redemtion on Python have not been very helpful, can you help with a guide?

Comment: The sample script above assumes you are already using Outlook Object Model, but in theory you can replace setting the `MAPIOBJECT` line with calling `session.Logon`. I think there is some confusion here - Outlook rules are not created just when you want to process some message. They are created once and fire up every time an incoming message hits the Inbox (subject to optional conditions).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Suppose I want to use this Rule I created, Would I be using the commnd,  NewMsg = oldmessage.Redirect()?

Comment: No, rules have nothing to do with any particular message - take a look at them in Outlook: click File | Rules And Alerts. You create a rule once and use it for years to come - it just sits there and gets applied every time a new message arrives (if the condition matches). You don't run newly created server rules against any messages that you have already received.

Answer (score 0):

> I cant use send On behalf of an send Using Account as it means I need to have the original sender in my mailbox.

There is a difference between the two.

The send using account feature requires another account to be configured in the Outlook profile, see the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. The send On behalf of another person requires permissions from the mailbox owner, the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property returns a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.

Comment: You are correct, both features cannot solve my issue